# List all maps in my Portal and list their corresponding layers

Tags: layers, feature-layer, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to list all of the maps inside of my Portal with the corresponding features that are inside.  So far this is my code:

```
# Import necessary modules
import arcgis
import openpyxl

# Create an ArcGIS Portal connection
portal = arcgis.gis.GIS("<your ArcGIS portal URL>", "<your ArcGIS portal username>", "your ArcGIS portal password>")

# Search for all maps in the portal
maps = portal.content.search(query="type:Web Map", item_type="Web Map", max_items=1000)

# Create an Excel workbook and worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# Add a header row to the worksheet
worksheet.append(["Title", "ID", "URL"])

# Iterate through the maps and add a row for each map
for map in maps:
    worksheet.append([map.title, map.id, map.url])


# Save the workbook
workbook.save(MapList.xlsx')
```

This code seems to work in that it gives me all of my maps. However, whenever I add in code to try to print the layer names within the map it bombs out.

Here's an example of what I just mentioned.

```
# Search for all maps in the portal
maps = portal.content.search(query="type:Web Map", item_type="Web Map", max_items=1000)

# Create an Excel workbook and worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# Add a header row to the worksheet
worksheet.append(["Map Title", "layerType Title", "layerType ID"])

# Iterate through the maps
for map in maps:
    # Access the map's layers
    map_layers = map.layers
    
    # Iterate through the map's layers
    for layerType in map_layers:
        # Add a row for the layerType
        worksheet.append([map.title, layerType.title, layerType.id])
```

Comment: Could you add some additional info to this? What Traceback do you get? How are you implementing the code? Where does it fail?

Comment: Does “bombs out” involve receiving an error message?  If so, please include it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for I am not very good at python or for that fact any other scripting language.  However I was able to take this code: https://github.com/joshsharpheward/gis-administration/blob/master/find_unused_services.py
And modify it like so to get an excel document and it was the results I was looking for.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

def main():
    # logs into active portal in ArcGIS Pro
    gis = GIS('pro')

    arcpy.AddMessage("Logged into {} as {}".format(arcpy.GetActivePortalURL(), gis.properties['user']['username']))

    # creates list of items of all map image, feature, vector tile and image services (up to 10000 of each) in active portal
    services = (gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Map Service", max_items=10000) +
                gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Feature Service", max_items=10000) +
                gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Vector Tile Service", max_items=10000) +
                gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Image Service", max_items=10000))

    arcpy.AddMessage('Searching webmaps in {}'.format(arcpy.GetActivePortalURL()))

    # creates list of items of all webmaps in active portal
    web_maps = gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Web Map", max_items = 10000)

    # Create an empty data frame to store the data
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Web Map', 'Service URL'])

    # loops through list of webmap items
    for item in web_maps:
        # creates a WebMap object from input webmap item
        web_map = WebMap(item)
        # accesses basemap layer(s) in WebMap object
        basemaps = web_map.basemap['baseMapLayers']
        # accesses layers in WebMap object
        layers = web_map.layers

        # loops through basemap layers
        for bm in basemaps:
            # tests whether the bm layer has a styleUrl(VTS) or url (everything else)
            if 'styleUrl'in bm.keys():
                for service in services:
                    if service.url in bm['styleUrl']:
                        services.remove(service)
            elif 'url' in bm.keys():
                for service in services:
                    if service.url in bm['url']:
                        services.remove(service)

        # loops through layers
        for layer in layers:
            # Add a new row to the data frame for each service used in the web map
            if hasattr(layer, 'styleUrl'):
                df.loc[len(df)] = [item.title, layer.styleUrl]
            elif hasattr(layer, 'url'):
                df.loc[len(df)] = [item.title, layer.url]

    # Save the data frame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel('web_maps.xlsx', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```